# How to format a dateTime-string into FullDatetimeFormat of a different culture?

Tags: powershell, datetime, cultureinfo

I need a string-output of a dateTime-Value in the FullDateTime-format of a different culture.
The result should be identical to the output of this command on a system running under the target-culture (here 'de-DE'):

```
$date = [datetime]::new(2022,2,28,10,33,0)
$date.ToString('F')
# Montag, 28. Februar 2022 10:33:00
```

This is the Powershell-code that I expected to work:

```
$de = [cultureInfo]::new('de-DE') # sample of any target-culture
[datetime]::ParseExact($date, $de.DateTimeFormat.FullDateTimePattern, $de)
```

...but that throws an error.

I cannot work with a fixed string format in ParseExact in my project, because I need to respect any (manual) modification of the DateTime-format made for that culture.

Comment: Wouldn't the output always respect the format of the system culture?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer was so easy at the end. 'toString' has a 2nd parameter:

```
$date = [datetime]::new(2022,2,28,10,33,0)
$de = [cultureInfo]::new('de-DE')
$date.ToString($de.DateTimeFormat.FullDateTimePattern, $de)
```

That works for any other target-cultures in the same way.